# Algorithm to summarize dates as daily, weekday, and/or specific days between two dates

Tags: algorithm, date, calendar, schedule, summarization

I have a list of dates I am trying to summarize in the most concise version. I am working with VBA (I know) but can expand to use python and SQL if needed.

The overall document has a start date and an end date. Also provided is a list of dates (between the start and end date). This list of dates is what I am trying to summarize in the most concise version.

My original plan was to calculate three strings for the list and compare and return the shortest string.
The three strings were as follows:

1. Daily (With exceptions)

- Looped from document start date to end date and returned "Daily - Except xx, xx, xx" where xx were days between the document start and end that were not in the list of dates.
- Date ranges were included. "Daily - Except May 15 to 19" vs "Daily - Except May 15, 16, 17, 18, 19"

2. Specific Days

- Looped through list of dates and returned a sorted list with date ranges if needed. "May 15 to 19, 23-29"

3. Weekday (and exceptions)

- For each day of week return the day of week (and exceptions)
- Weekday should turn to range if applicable. I.e. "Mon, Tue, Wed, Fri" should instead be "Mon to Wed, Fri"
- Exceptions should be at the end. I.e. " Mon - Except May 15, Tue - Except May 16, Wed - Except May 17" should instead be "Mon to Wed - Except May 15 to 17"

I have already created the code for 1. and 2. above but 3. is mostly why I am reaching out.

1. Not sure if I am trying to reinvent the wheel. Does an algorythm already exist that sort of does what I am trying to do? I have tried to look but my search came up short.
2. Am I approaching this wrong? Is there a better way to achive the same outcome?
3. I am having trouble wrapping my head on how to address 3. above. For example, lets say for arguments sake, that in this case "Tue - Except May 16" and "May 9" are both "correct" strings for Tuesdays. The problem that I am having is that when I get to the point of deciding if "Tue - Except May 16" is best I don't know how the rest of the weekdays will end up. The "ideal" could be "Mon to Fri - Except May 16" (Tue gets added to the range) or it could be "Fri and May 9".

Comment: Are you sure you want such a text description? Wouldn't a calendar-like image be more concise, or something like github activity grid?

Comment: A calendar-like image is great idea and it is considered longer term but I need a text string at this time. Each document has 10-30 list of dates to be summarized into a one page document.

Comment: Cheap and dirty solution -- try all possible ways to group weekdays into consecutive ranges (you can even allow "Sat to Tue"). Each group can be described either as a list of separate days, or as "A to B - Except X, Y, Z", except "A to A" is just "A". Then all groups are joined in a single string and the shortest string over all possible splits wins.

Comment: And of course a group can be just an empty string if there are no active dates. Without wraparound like I mentioned there are only 64 possible splits, 128 with, so it should be fast enough.